# How can I get ctags to generate tags for a yeoman generated AngularJS webapp completely?

Tags: yeoman, ctags, jsctags

I have an AngularJS project that was scaffolded using yeoman. I want to use ctags to generate tags for the whole project so that I can navigate the code in vim. But when I use the command

```
ctags -R .
```

in the root folder, it generates tags for folders at one or two levels deeper relative to root. The folders at 5-6 levels deeper are not tagged by ctags. How can I get it to work for the whole project?
I am using **exuberant-ctags** for generating tags.
OS : Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same results with the following?

```
ctags -R *
```

What OS? Have you verified it's NOT a permissions issue?

Comment: Same results with the above mentioned command. It is not a permission issue. OS is Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

ctags uses the file extension to correctly choose the parser that it will use to generate the tags file. It's possible that the files you are not finding have an unsupported extension.

Another possibility is that those files are using language extensions not supported by Exuberant Ctags. In which case you might want to try [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags), which was forked from Exuberant and is in active development. It is possible that the JS parser was improved in this fork of ctags.